# Django settings SECRET_KEY

Tags: python, django-1.8

I have the following structure of my project

```
project
--project
----settings
------base.py
------development.py
------testing.py
------secrets.json
--functional_tests
--manage.py
```

**development.py** and **testing.py** 'inherit' from **base.py**

```
from .base import *
```

So, where I have problems

I have the SECRET_KEY for Django in secrets.json, which is stored in **settings** folder

I load this key like this (saw this in "Two scoops of Django")

```
import json
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

key = "secrets.json"
with open(key) as f:
    secrets = json.loads(f.read())

def get_secret(setting, secret=secrets):
    try:
        return secrets[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the {} environment variable".format(setting)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

SECRET_KEY = get_secret("SECRET_KEY")
```

But when I run `python manage.py runserver`

> Blah-blah-blah
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

After some investigations I got the following

1. If I put `print(os.getcwd())` inside **base.py** I get `/media/grimel/Home/project/` instead of `/media/grimel/Home/project/project/settings/`
2. This code works only if I replace:
   `key = "secrets.json"`
   by
   `key = "project/settings/secrets.json"`

Personally, I don't like this solution.
So, questions:

1. Why, for base.py current working directory is so confusing?
2. What's a better approach in solving this problem?

Comment: Why don't you like that solution? The alternative would prevent you from referencing anything lower than your current directory (or would require you to do `../../x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working directory is based on how you run the program, in your case `python manage.py runserver` hints that your working directory is the one containing `manage.py`. Beware that this can vary when run as WSGI script or otherwise, so your concern with using `key = "project/settings/secrets.json"` is valid.

One solution is to use the value of `__file__` in `base.py`, likely to be `"project/settings/base.py"`. I would use something like

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
key = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "secrets.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make life simpler why not move `secrets.json` to your project root and reference

```
import os    
key = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "secrets.json")
```

directly. This is platform independent saving you the need to override `BASE_DIR` at all in your settings file. Don't forget to add your settings file to version control.